# WebBrowser controls multi sessionC#

Tags: c#, session, cookies, webbrowser-control

I have more than one WebBrowser controls in my program, and it seams they all share session cookies.  What I would like is that they DON'T share the session cookies.

I have different WebBrowser controls that open the same website with different accounts, or open the same webpage that stores different data in session.

Comment: ASP.NET Session State Overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Hi user3501155, I'm glad you don't want to share session cookies between your browser controls, cookies have nothing to do with .NET "browser" controls, but that's ok.  Why don't you try making a custom cookie in your code and accessing it as needed.  Feel free to post the results of your attempt as well as clarify specifically what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive - note that information on session state will not help in any way to prevent sharing "session cookies" (cookies without expiration set) between instances of WebBrowserControl (IE) in the same process. Unfortunately 2 concepts have the same name (which also likely not known by OP).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately what you are trying to achieve is not possible with the WebBrowser control, unless they are running in different processes. All instances of a WebBrowser inside the same process will always share same cookies - WebBrowser controls' sessions are isolated by process.

There is [`an alternative`](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/a-real-wpf-webbrowser/) to the standard WebBrowser control based on Awesomium which you might check out.